# I rewrote a nongrammatical sentence in a casual conversation

Tags: grammar, adverb-placement

> So, here’s another problem: how many people do you need in a room for
> there to be more than likely to have two people with the same
> birthday?

I tried and rewrote the above sentence as below.

**1. how many people do you need in a room for there to be more than likely at least two people with the same birthday?**

**2. how many people do you need in a room more than likely to have two people with the same birthday?**

1. Which sentence is more natural?
2. Considering 'more than likely' is an adverbial phrase meaning 'more likely than not : probably' in [Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more%20than%20likely), what is the most natural position of the phrase in the rewritten sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither sentence is really correct, I suggest

> How many people do you need in a room for ***it*** to be more than likely ***that*** at least two of them ***have*** the same birthday?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Or **share** the same birthday.